# Post link variable after click and change the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

Here's the HTML code

```
<span><a class="like-button" href="#" id="7">Like</a><span class="likeCount">25</span></span>
```

Here's the script for changing but i also want to post the link id and add 1 in likeCount IF user like and minus 1 if user unlike ! Same like we use on FB

```
$(function() {
    $('.like-button').click(function(){
        var obj = $(this);
        if( obj.data('liked') ){
            obj.data('liked', false);
            obj.html('Like');
        }
        else{
            obj.data('liked', true);
            obj.html('Unlike');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Heres hint `obj.siblings('.likeCount').text()`

Comment: doesnot make sense ... post where??

Comment: Do you want it client-side or server-side. If you are using this things, after a refresh , it would dissappear

Comment: likepost.cfm if user like and unlikepost.cfm if user unlike

Comment: @liquidsmoke: you want the local dom data be reflected based on like/unlike and also want to hit the  respective .cfm files  ? but what i dont get is that, what doesn the .cfm file do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can increment/decrement the value of the like count by 1 like this

```
 $('.like-button').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var likeCount=0; 
        var likeUnlikebit=0;
        if($(this).text()=="Like") {
             likeUnlikebit=1;
             $(this).text('Unlike'); 
        } 
        else
        {
             likeUnlikebit=-1;
             $(this).text('Like'); 
        }
        likeCount=parseInt($(this).siblings('.likeCount').text());
        $(this).siblings('.likeCount').text(likeCount+likeUnlikebit);
 });
```

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('.like-button').click(function(){
    var obj = $(this);
    if( obj.data('liked') ){
        obj.data('liked', false);
        obj.html('Like');
    $('.likeCount').html(parseFloat($('.likeCount').html())-1);       
    }
    else{
        obj.data('liked', true);
        obj.html('Unlike');
         $('.likeCount').html(parseFloat($('.likeCount').html())+1);
    }
});
});
```